# In SSMS, what is the number shown to the right of the login name?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I looked into the properties of the connection, and did not see anything matching the number.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is session id or to be more precise `SQL Server Process ID`. Same as:

```
SELECT @@SPID;
```

To check all sessions you could use `sp_who`/[`sp_whoisactive`](http://whoisactive.com/) or SSMS Activity Monitor.

SSMS -> Object Explorer -> Right-Click on instance name -> Activity Monitor -> Processes

Comment: Hmmm. On my system, I don't see a PID of #74 when I look at the Windows Task Manager.  But you're right that it is the SPID.

Comment: @Sabuncu Windows Task Manager :) `EXEC sp_who` instead

Comment: Thank you, I see that it maintains its own list of IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Its the SPID (basically session ID) from your session in SQL server.

If you run the sp_who2 stored proc you can see more information.